# Java Generic WildCard Lower Bound: List<? super Father> list = new ArrayList<>()

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

why does it work? 
I understood taht "? super Father" only allows Father and GrandFather

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki5N3.png)

Code here-------------------

 

public class RxTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    // extends -> read only
    // super -> write only

    List<? super Father> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(new Child());
    list.add(new Child());

    System.out.println(list.size()); // 2

    // why does it work? I understood taht "? super Father" only allows Father and GrandFather


}
```

}

class GrandFather {
}

class Father extends GrandFather {
}

class Child extends Father {
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Comment: Post code into your question instead of attaching it as an image

Comment: Hmm.. I think this comes down to  a List<Object>?

Comment: Your question is an entirely reasonable one - just [edit] it to include the code in the image instead of the image.

Comment: By the way, `super` is a *lower* bound, not an upper bound, as indicated in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Don't read "`? super Father`" as "everything is a supertype of `Father`".

Read it as "*the expected type of elements in this list* is a supertype of `Father`". This may seem like I'm saying the same thing, but it is not the same.

It is saying that the thing which created the *actual* list (not the wildcarded reference) expects everything in the list to be of a particular type, and that type is a supertype of `Father`. You can't create a `new ArrayList<? super/extends Something>`, it has to be a `new ArrayList<Something>`.

As such, you can add instances of `Father` (which includes subtypes, like `Child`), without violating the expectations on the elements in the list.

Remember [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/3788176):

> Producer extends, Consumer super

`List<? super Father>` is a *consumer* of instances of `Father`.

This is *not* the same as "`super -> write only`" as in your code. You can still read from lower-bounded lists, you just have to treat everything as `Object`.

Similarly, `extends` does not mean "read only": you can add existing elements from the list to itself, as well as adding literal `null`.

Comment: "Similarly, extends does not mean "read only": you can add existing elements from the list to itself" Only if you capture the wildcard into a type variable. It won't work with just a wildcard.

Comment: @newacct yes, but you can pass a wildcarded list into a method which captures the type variable, so the list being wildcarded in a method is no protection against writing to itself.